# Are there any SMTP to HTTP free services (Email to POST)?

Tags: http, email, smtp

I was pointed to the service [smtp2web](http://www.smtp2web.com/) a while back, but I've been trying it out and it doesn't seem to work.  Are there any others out there?  Any way to accomplish this in ruby?

I write an email and send it to `lanceJpollard@smtp2web` and get this response immediately:

> Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:
>
> ```
>  lanceJpollard@smtp2web.com
> ```
>
> Technical details of permanent failure:
>    Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 Cannot receive for specified address (state 14).
>
> ----- Original message -----
>
> MIME-Version: 1.0
>    Received: by 10.231.80.213 with SMTP id u21mr6871412ibk.173.1282618290464;
>     Mon, 23 Aug 2010 19:51:30 -0700 (PDT)
>    Received: by 10.231.185.135 with HTTP; Mon, 23 Aug 2010 19:51:30 -0700 (PDT)
>    Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2010 21:51:30 -0500
>    Message-ID: 
>    Subject: Hello
>    From: Lance Pollard 
>    To: lanceJpollard 
>    Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=0015176f0f3495fbba048e88d7b8
>
> asdfasdf

Any ideas?

**Update**

Duntadada: [Sendgrid](http://wiki.sendgrid.com/doku.php).

> Point a subdomain MX record to our server, we parse incoming emails and post attachments and body contents to your web forms. Useful to have uploads@subdomain.yourdomain.com or interact with users through email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a small Google App Engine app which receives the email and then posts it to wherever you want using urlfetch.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/

App Engine is free unless you have a lot of traffic.

It supports Python or Java, not Ruby though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit of a plug but I have been developing http://cloudmailin.com to do exactly this. It's currently in beta but the aim is to always have a free version.

Comment: great to know! when you have a free version let me know.  sendgrid does this too, free 200 emails a day.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is https://zapier.com/. They offer a free plan if your usage is low and paid services if you exceed the limited free service. The key advantage is that you can not only receive the emails that then trigger an outgoing HTTP webhook action but you can extract email contents using the connected https://parser.zapier.com/ service. The parsing service will allow filtering out unrelated emails, where only valid contents will then trigger other connected services. Likewise the extracted values can be pass to another HTTP webhook service.